# What is the Key of 'Cuts Like a knife'

Tags: theory

While trying to improve my music theory, I found myself confused by this song ( Cuts like a Knife-Bryan Adams). On many sites on the internet I have read that the Key is D Major. The chord structure doesn't fit as the C chord rules that out. If I play the solo note for note, I found myself playing in D Mixolydian...Does any one else agree that this is the Key ?...and if so can you tell me where the A(Major?) chord is borrowed from, as D Mixolydian has an A minor. 
It's not a secondary dominant as the next chord is not a D. The parent Major scale of D Mixolydian is G...G's parallel minor is Bb...that has an 'A' but its's diminshed...so i'm very confused.
Hope someone can answer these 2 questions.

Comment: G's parallel minor is Gm.    G's *relative* minor is Em.    Gm is the *relative* minor *of* Bb.

Comment: I have voted to reopen as it's not so much about the song itself as the 'strange' chords within. Maybe you could re-word the question with no reference to one particular song. Read the help centre rules, and you'll see that it's not because you can't read music. A lot of our questions are from non-readers. We're just not that precious here, although you seem to have that impression, which is erroneous, generally speaking.

Answer (score 2):

You've fallen into the trap of believing music theory is music law. It isn't. It tries (very hard) to explain what happens - not really what *should* happen.

Many songs have chord structures that get explained by a bit of theory you maybe haven't met, till now. **Borrowed chords** are often used, so that the main chords from a key, say D major, (D, Em, F#m, G, A, Bm, C#o) are used, but supplemented with those from the **parallel minor**. (Here, Dm, Eo, F, Gm, Am, Bb, C).

Sometimes other 'foreign' chords creep in to songs, and while there will be theory which explains, or tries to, it isn't *that* important. The old adage of 'if it sounds good, it probably is' is so important...

Comment: Hi Tim....thanks for your reply and I take your point to not get hung up on everything having a reason in the future. I guess, looking a little deeper at my own question, it comes from looking for "Rules" I can understand to expand my musical knowledge and make my next song have that different twist. Example if I'm writing a song I can 'try' some of these things and see if they suit my song, rather than just tying every chord to see if it fits. I have learnt some new things recently ( like Secondary dominants and parallel minor) and was hoping this was a new 'Rule' to add to my arsenal. Cheers

Comment: Really... this question is "On Hold" because its Off topic. So as I didn't include sheet music. Well I cant read sheet music...I'm a guitarist for Christ's sake. So, Dom the moderator...can you suggest a Forum I can join where the Moderator's aren't so picky... and someone who has some limited musical knowledge can post a reasonable question